# AndroidX Q material component not working

Tags: android, androidx, material-components-android

I have just started a new project with the latest version of Android studio 3.5.2. Min API - 19 and using SDK Q, which forces us to use AndroidX.

```
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

> Giving error: Android resource linking failed.

With this setup, I am trying to user Material Component, but it is not working.

I am not sure if anything changed in AndroidX or Material component is already included or not. However, I have added the material dependency anyway.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // here is the one
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
}
```

So my issue is how can I use material components on this setup.

[image]

Comment: When do you receive *Giving error: Android resource linking failed.*? Add more details

Comment: When I built an app to preview. Another thing I have noticed on the Design mode it that element not showing any property or constraint option. This is a brand new project nothing in it yet and this is the first screen and element I have added. Please let me know if you need any specific details or info so I can share it.

Comment: Try to post the details of the error. *Android resource linking failed* should be related to a layout for example

Comment: This issue is resolved after clear cache and restart. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciated.